# Comment dire que j'aime créer des histoires ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation, curriculum-vitae

J'ai un CV dont je suis content, mais je n'arrive pas à formuler de façon satisfaisante cette partie dans 'Centres d'intérêt':

> La création d'histoires, que ce soit pour les raconter ou les écrire.

Je ne peux pas appeler cela "écrire" dans la mesure où je ne les écris pas toutes, et je ne vois pas d'autre façon de le dire.

Help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pour parler du processus de création d'histoire, du fait de les conter ou de les écrire, j'emploierais le mot **narration**.

Sur [wiki](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narration) :

> La narration désigne un récit détaillé, mais aussi la structure générale de ce récit. Dans la rhétorique antique, il s’agit de la seconde partie du discours après l’exorde, celle où l’orateur fait le récit des faits.

---

Si ça ne te plait pas, il est aussi possible d'utiliser *"conception de fictions"* ou plus simplement "**[fiction](https://www.unige.ch/lettres/framo/enseignements/methodes/fiction/fiintegr.html)**".

NB : Ton CV est intéressant pour te faire repérer mais ce n'est pas le choix d'un mot dans tes hobbies qui vont faire que tu auras le poste. Peut-être ta présentation de ceux-ci à l'oral : entraîne-toi surtout pour cela.

Comment: Merci pour ta réponse et pour la note. Effectivement, c'est un détail, mais ça me gênait. C'est chose faite !

Answer (score 1):

Bonjour,

Au vu des fonctionnements RH d'aujourd'hui, la rubrique Centre d'Intérêts est autant une présentation personnelle qu'une liste de ***Mots Clefs*** ; il n'est pas mal vu de faire une liste un peu plus longue, surtout si le CV est numérisé, pour le faire ressortir au travers des différents outils RH.

Si effectivement le mot **narration** est une bonne idée, le placer à côté de **rédaction** et de **création de fictions** (voire de *biographie* si c'est le cas) me semble une méthode efficace de vous décrire complètement. L'important est de vous démarquer de la masse.

Enfin, encore plus important, n'hésitez pas à numériser certains de vos travaux et les joindre à votre CV pour montrer votre travail et rassurer le recruteur.

> Le démonstratif vaut mieux que le déclaratif.

NB : Plus l'entreprise visée est importante, plus les candidatures sont nombreuses et plus la GRH aura tendance à faire un tri pour faire remonter des candidatures potentiellement plus intéressantes via des mots-clef

Comment: Comme l'a indiqué Nathan, il voudrait un terme qui regroupe l'écrit et l'oral et, du coup, le mot *rédaction* (comme *écriture*) ne convient pas.

Comment: Si on le regarde dans ce sens, oui ma réponse ne convient pas, mais j'ai proposé de rajouter rédaction en plus pour ressortir avec les mots clefs sur le CV, ce qui est aussi son objectif à la base

Comment: Merci pour la réponse. Pour le moment, mon CV est un fichier image parce qu'il est trop lourd en pdf (l'export depuis Photoshop n'est pas optimisé), mais j'ai effectivement comme projet de l'alléger pour le transformer en PDF. Je pourrais alors jouer sur les mots-clés.